# React + Storybook + Sass: SassError: expected "{"

Tags: reactjs, sass, storybook, sass-loader

I'm having issues trying to make Storybook read my `.scss` files. I've tried a bunch of different possible solutions, but none of those solved the problem. Here is the error that always pop up:

```
SassError: SassError: expected "{".
  ╷
1 │ var api = require("!../../../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js");
  │                                                                                                     ^
  ╵
```

There are no Sass errors in the project, since the app runs and loads the styles normally by `react-scripts start`.

Here is my project, if you want to reproduce the error:
https://github.com/tchesa/virtual-meeting-ui/tree/storybook

> make sure you are in branch `storybook`

In this example, i'm using `storybook-addon-sass-postcss` storybook's addon to setup sass loader, but i also tried push `sass-loader` to storybook's webpack through `webpackFinal` property and i ended in the same error.